# Referencing CSV Columns in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Say for example I have a csv file like this:

```
first_name last_name age
Dave wilson 24
... ... ...
```

When i try to reference the column to get a list of ages i get an error.

```
df = read_csv('people.csv')
print df['age']
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'age'
```

I also tried to reference it by column number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the separator as a param for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), the default is comma, here I use `\s+` which means multiple spaces:

```
In [234]:

t="""first_name last_name age
Dave wilson 24"""
​
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df['age']
Out[234]:
0    24
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

What you did resulted in this:

```
In [236]:

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
df.columns
Out[236]:
Index(['first_name last_name age'], dtype='object')
```

So it treated your header as a single column

Answer (score 0):

I think while reading you should specify the separator as

```
df = read_csv('people.csv', delimiter='\t')
```